# Encode GIF in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, midp, gif, lcdui

I have an Image object in J2ME and I'd like to enconde it to GIF.
I've already found a JPEG and PNG encoder as well, but I'm wondering if it's possible to encode my Image in the GIF format, returning it's byte array.

I'm doing something like this:

...

```
  Image img = Image.createImage(width, height);
    Graphics graphics = img.getGraphics();
//do some drawing stuff here
...
```

And finally I have an Image object.

Now I'd like to encode it to GIF like:

```
 byte[] gifBytes = GIFEncoder.encode(img);
```

Where can I find one?

thanks!

Comment: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=617676

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [J2ME Animated GIF encoder](http://www.jappit.com/blog/2008/12/04/j2me-animated-gif-encoder/),

**Usage:**

Usage is quite straightforward, and it requires these steps:

- Instantiate your AnimatedGifEncoder object
- Start it, by passing an OutputStream as argument (e.g.: a ByteArrayOutputStream)
- Add your Image objects by using addFrame() method
- Finalize it by calling finish()

Comment: That's the only I've found. Thanks.